# OCR number format correction and conversion

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace, ocr

I am working with an OCR package to extract monetary amount values from documents. Occasionally the decimal point will be incorrectly OCR'd as a comma. The software can do character replacement, out-of-the-box, but I can't just replace all ',' with '.' because of the "thousands comma". The software allows for customer scripts to be written for validating and correcting values, in various languages. I'm using C#. I've experimented with various ways to do this, from sub-string replacement, to regex replacement, to Double.Parse with globalization and number styles, etc. What would you all recommend to achieve all of the following conversions?

```
12.345,67 ->  12345.67
12345.67  ->  12345.67 (no change)
12,345.67 ->  12345.67
1,234.56  ->  1234.56
1.234.56  ->  1234.56
1.234,56  ->  1234.56
123,45    ->  123.45
123.45    ->  123.45 (no change) 
1234      ->  1234.00
1,234     ->  1234.00
123       ->  123.00
```

Edit. Added more examples, based on questions asked.
Note: Values will be in dollars-and-cents. No need to handle "tenths of a cent". OCR'd value will either have two or zero decimal places.

Comment: What about `123,456`?

Comment: Well, because these are dollar values, and won't have three decimal places...
123,456 -> 123456.00
12,345 -> 12345.00

Answer (score 0):

I would do 2 replaces and a simple check, I'm not familiar with C# but Javascript would be:

```
var newVal = value.replace(/[,.](?=\d{3,})/g, '').replace(',', '.');
if (newVal.indexOf('.')==-1)
  newVal = newVal + '.00';
```

Do the examples you give encompass every possible scenario? Or do you deal with stuff like more than 2 decimal, 1 decimal that needs an additional 0 like `123,4 -> 123.40`?

***Edit*** Changed so that `1.234.567,89` will come out as `1234567.89`, this assumes though that the currency doesn't allow more than 2 decimals. This is normal in everyday life but there are cases where those 10th of a cent do matter (stock markets, interest-rates). So depending on the use-cases you might wanna be more thorough in determining which is which, decimal-point or 1000-separator.

Working **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbkcuhxy/)**

Comment: Upon further pondering I realize that a case like `1,234` should be taken into account. You probably want that to come out like `1234` rather than `1.234`... Neither mine nor @Tensibai's solution accounts for that.

Comment: Values will only be "dollars and cents", so will only have two or zero decimal places. No need to handle tenths of a cent.

Comment: My solution would handle that correctly then, any `,` or `.` that has 3 or more digits right after it are deleted and any `,` left (must have 2 digits behind it then) is converted to a `.`. The last part simply checks whether cents are displayed and if not adds it.

Answer (score 0):

The best idea I went up with:

use this regex `(?:[.,]?)(\d+)` on each line and then work on the number of time the capture groups was ok.

1. If once: add .00
2. If twice : join first and second with a dot
3. If more: join all but the last and join the last with a .

I'm not familiar enought with C# to give a code exmple, but could do search if really needed.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning up after OCR is a tough job. Whatever you do, you will eventually get something wrong, so manual check is absolutely necessary. My advice

1. Try scanning in higher DPI, 300 is old standard, I prefer 400.
2. Use image processing toolkits to clear your images. Try TMSSequoia if you can, they are ridiculously 
   good.
3. I do not know which engine you use, but most of the engines gives you an estimation of correctness for each character. Use this info
4. Many engines provide language/charset settings for different recognition blocks. Try English (US)/ Numeric with your blocks if you know where they are. I had once used this to read Turkish financial data from fax documents.
5. Clean obvious first (Oo -> 0, l -> 1)
6. Then clean problematic (B -> 13, L -> 1.)
7. And then try cleaning by looking at your samples.

Comment: I'm using ABBYY FlexiCapture. ABBYY's OCR engine is very good and does have confidence level.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer one single regular expression, this little monster might do the trick:

```
^
   (?:
      (?:
         (\d{1,3})
         (?: [.,] (\d{3}) )?
         (?: [.,] (\d{3}) )?
         (?: [.,] (\d{3}) )?
      )
      |
      (\d+)
   )
   (?:
      [.,] (\d\d)
   )?
$
```

Replace with `\1\2\3\4\5.\6`.

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/zE5mK7/1)

Note that it only handles amounts up to `$999.999.999.999,99`, if you work for government, feel free to add more `[.,]` groups )).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it the long way. I wouldn't call it inelegant, but it's longer than I wanted.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(strTotalIncGST);
if (strTotalIncGST.Length > 3)
{
    int decPos = strTotalIncGST.Length - 3;
    if (sb[decPos] == ',')
    {
        sb.Remove(decPos, 1);
        sb.Insert(decPos, ".");
    }
}
if (strTotalIncGST.Length > 7)
{
    int thouPos = strTotalIncGST.Length - 7;
    if (sb[thouPos] == '.' || sb[thouPos] == ',')
    {
        sb.Remove(thouPos, 1);
    }
}
```

and then use `double.TryParse()` to convert to double, then back to string with `.ToString("F2")` for formatting to two decimal places.